# Java Duration Class, cannot resolve to a type

Tags: java, time, duration, localtime, temporal

I am trying to find the difference in time between two LocalTime objects in HH:MM:SS format and **my duration object is giving me the error** *Duration.between cannot be resolved to a type*. The between description on Java docs explicitly says LocalTime objects are valid- do I have to translate my objects into LocalDateTime objects with zones for Duration to work?

Only other theory on this issue would be my placement of this class in my Make file, but I would think my import would take care of the issue during compilation. Code below:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.Duration;


public class Station {
    int stationNumber;
    String stationAddress;
    ArrayList<Driver> drivers;
    ArrayList<Road> roads;          
    double[][] roadMap;             

    public Station(int sNumber, String sAddress) {
        stationNumber = sNumber;
        stationAddress = sAddress;
        drivers = new ArrayList<Driver>();
        
        roads = new ArrayList<Road>(5);
        roadMap = new double[5][5];
    }

    public static void calculateNewTimes(ArrayList<roadDataToBeSorted> delDataIncreasingTime) {
        LocalTime firstStop = LocalTime.parse(delDataIncreasingTime.get(0).rdDeliveryTime);
        LocalTime lastStop = LocalTime.parse(delDataIncreasingTime.get(delDataIncreasingTime.size()-1).rdDeliveryTime);
        Duration duration = new Duration.between(firstStop, lastStop); ***<-----ISSUE***
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`between` is a static factory method of `Duration` class, returning a `Duration` object.

So you don't need to create `Duration` object using the `new` keyword.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(firstStop, lastStop);
```

Comment: That's it, I looked too deep first. What does your process for diagnosing a bug look like? I need a better approach

Comment: Use a proper IDE (Intellij, Eclipse, ...), it will tell you such minor mistakes immediately.

Comment: I'm using VS code, so I definitely don't have the same level of support for Java. I like being able to work on several different languages in the same IDE, would you recommend I get tailored IDE's? I primarily work with the MEAN stack

Comment: Since Java allows you to call static methods via an instance, this is not the entire answer. The error message comes from the OP trying to create an instance of some nested class of `Duration` named `between` (note what follows the `new` keyword), which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: @GriffeyDog do you mean Java tries to create static nested class `between`? And yes we can create instance of Duration class, but I think it's not necessary

Comment: @CoolHands I didn't run your code, but I just got what the problem is in `Duration.between` statement

Comment: My approach for such a compiler error message that I don’t understand is very carefully comparing my own code with a working example. Only after I have tried hard to understand the message though: Asking myself “why does the compiler think that I am trying to use `Duration.between` as a type?”